# Is it possible to use all processors in Excel while refreshing a Bloomberg formula?

Tags: excel, add-in, processor, bloomberg

I am using the Bloomberg `BDH` formula to get United States Financial Statistics into Excel.

When I refresh the worksheet containing the formulas, the task manager displays the message that only 2 processors are being used.

My computer, however, has 4 processors to be used, according to the Excel Options tab.

I would like to know if there is a way to use all the processors when I update the Bloomberg data using the BBG add-in.

Comment: Have you confirmed that Excel uses all 4 processors when running other scripts? Make sure that "Enable multi-threaded processing" is enabled from the Options - Advance Menu (though should considering already using 2). What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I already have multi-thread processing enabled and I am on Excel 2010. Other tasks use all processors, the Bloomberg update uses only two of them